# F# mergesort tail-recursion

Tags: f#

I tried to write a tail recursive code for mergesort. The code does compile and run. However, the output is wrong. It only outputs one integer. I was wondering how I would fix this code so that the list of integers are sorted and outputted.

```
let rec merge L L2 P = 
  match L, L2 with
  | [], [] -> P
  | [], _  -> L2
  | _,  [] -> L
  | hd::t1, hd2::t2 ->
    if hd <= hd2 then
       merge t1 L2 (P @ [hd])
    else
       merge L t2 (P @ [hd2])


//
// mergesort:
//
let rec ms L  = 
  match L with
  | []    -> []
  | e::[] -> L
  | _     -> 
    let mid = List.length L / 2
    let (L, L2) = List.splitAt mid L
    merge (ms L) (ms L2) []
```

Comment: `merge` looks fishy to me - when exactly one list is empty, then `P` does not affect the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is in function `merge`: imagine you sort the list `[2;1]`. It turns to `merge [2] [1] []`, then to `merge [] [2] [1]`, and finally second case of `match` yields [2]. Second and third cases of `match` must account for `P` somehow.

In fact, you absolutely do not need to manipulate 3 lists in your `merge`, two is quite enough if we refactor it to:

```
let rec merge l1 l2 =
    match (l1,l2) with
    | (x,[]) -> x
    | ([],y) -> y
    | (x::tx,y::ty) ->
        if x <= y then x::merge tx l2
        else y::merge l1 ty
```

and change the last line of `ms` to `merge (ms L) (ms L2)` - and this variant does work as expected:

`ms List<int>.Empty` returns `[]`

`ms [2;1]` returns `[1;2]`

e.t.c

**Update**: As @kvb pointed out the `merge` function above is not tail recursive. This is correct and refactoring it to tail-recursive version requires  more involvement by introducing an accumulator `acc` being filled via `continuation` function:

```
let merge l1 l2 =
  let rec mergeAux continuation l1 l2 = 
    match l1, l2 with
    | l1, [] -> continuation l1
    | [], l2 -> continuation l2
    | x::tx, y::ty ->
      if x <= y then mergeAux (fun acc -> continuation(x::acc)) tx l2
      else mergeAux (fun acc -> continuation(y::acc)) l1 ty
  mergeAux id l1 l2
```

Now the implementation is tail-recursive that is easy to check with:

```
let rand = System.Random() in
    List.init 1000000 (fun _ -> rand.Next(-10000,10000)) |> ms
>
val it : int list =
  [-10000; -10000; -10000; -10000; -10000; -10000; -10000; ...
```

Comment: Note, though, that your version of `merge` is no longer tail recursive.

Comment: Good catch, @kvb, updated the answer. Thank you, Keith!

Answer (score -1):

Even after the changes made for the accepted answer you still do not have a tail recursive merge sort.  The last line of the merge sort `merge (ms L) (ms L2)` calls `ms` twice then calls `merge`.  In order for a function to be tail recursive your function must end with at most one recursive call to itself.  This scenario is where continuations are needed. By passing a continuation you can make one call to `ms` and pass it a continuation that makes the second call to `ms` and pass that second call another continuation that makes the call to `merge`.  I would actually remove the continuation from the `merge` function as it is not needed and it makes the `merge` function more difficult to read than implementing it with an accumulator parameter.  Lastly, for easy callability from the outside, I would nest the `merge` function as well as the `ms` function inside of a `mergeSort` function that only takes one list parameter, There's no need to expose the rest of the details to callers.  My implementation of a fully tail recursive merge sort in F# would be as follows:

```
let mergeSort ls =
    let rec merge l1 l2 res = 
        match l1, l2 with
        | [], [] -> res |> List.rev
        | x::xs, [] -> merge xs [] (x::res)
        | [], y::ys -> merge [] ys (y::res)
        | x::xs, y::ys when x < y -> merge xs (y::ys) (x::res)
        | xs, y::ys -> merge xs ys (y::res)

    let rec ms ls cont =
        match ls with
        | [] -> cont []
        | [x] -> cont [x]
        | xs ->
            let ys, zs = List.splitAt ((List.length xs) / 2) xs
            ms ys (fun ys' -> ms zs (fun zs' -> cont (merge ys' zs' [])))
    ms ls id
```

Note that there are ways to do this more efficiently in terms of memory usage, which would likely also help the speed due to less memory allocations,  but since that is beyond the scope of this question I'm not going to get into that in the answer.